# How to apply a glyphicon to a button when marked as active in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to add in a glyphicon of a check mark next to the word once it's been clicked by the user. Imagine you click the button TEST and the entire button changes color and a checkmark shows to the left of the word test.

I have the following:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn wk-prd-btn" style="margin-right: 15px;"><span class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>TEST</button>
```

Then for CSS I have:

```
.wk-prd-btn:focus {
  background-color: #e74481;
  color: white;
}

.wk-prd-btn:hover {
  background-color: #e74481;
  color: white;
}
```

I've considered putting a div around the button and doing an overlay in the CSS but then that affects the text for the button itself which I don't want to do. Any suggestions on how to handle?

Answer (score 0):

Used the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click"> MUG</button>
```

Then in the CSS:

```
.wk-click:focus:before{
  content: "";
  font-family: "fontawesome";
}
```

Just need to get the buttons to maintain their click. Hopefully my blunder helps others.